# How to prevent legs from stretching when moving other parts of body?

Tags: modeling, dimensions

[image]

I wanted to move this part of the leg as highlighted in the image

[image]

As you can see this part of the leg becomes stretched and thinned really weirdly. Does anyone know how to prevent the leg from becoming thinned and stretched really weirdly and to prevent the dimensions from changing?

Comment: Are you modelling (making the mesh shape) or rigging (making bones to do animations easily)?

Comment: I am rigging. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are some tips to fix your problem.

1. subdivide
2. weight paint
3. preserve volume

## 1. subdivide

For a "good" rigging, your model seems to be too low poly. I suggest you add some loop cuts (near the joint) or add a subdivision surface modifier above the armature modifier.
Make sure that your new vertecies have appropriate vertex weights.

## 2. weight paint

By using weight painting, you can manipulate "the influence of the bone on a certain vertex". If some of your vertecies seem to move too much, decrease the vertex weight, mainly at the vertex paint mode.

## 3. preserve volume

At the Armature modifier panel, there is a check box labeled "preseve volume". Ticking it may improve your armature deform.

Comment: Where is the Armature modifier panel located @Allosteric?

Comment: When you set your armature as the parent of your mesh, you will get an Armature modifier in your mesh.

Comment: Oh ok thanks :) How would I know how many loop cuts I need to prevent my legs from deforming?

Comment: I guess one above and one below the existing loop would be enough. If that doesn't appear wonderful, taking a close look at models by others (especially at joints of character models) would help.

Answer (score -1):

i recommend setting up IK since you arent animating using rotation alone.

Comment: Hi. Please expand this answer to explain *how* the user should set up IK.